# phantomjs node page.open never execute on success

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I'm trying to use phantomjs and node for testing but i can't open page with it. Execution stop processing when i pass a correct url. Code execute on bad url.

work with failure if server=http://localhost:3001

don't work with success if server=http://localhost:3000

```js
phantom.create(function (ph) {
        console.log('createPage');
        ph.createPage(function (page) {
            console.log('open');
            page.open(server,function(status) {
                console.log('Status: '+status);
               if ( status !== "success" ) {
                    console.log('Unable to load '+ server) ;
                    ph.exit();
                }
                else {
                    console.log('success loaded wait for ready') ;
                ... ...
```

The error appear with grunt and buster

grunt test

but with

node test/node-test-index.js the code is executed with this stack trace

```
Status: success
success loaded wait for ready
other
'waitFor()' timeout
Uncaught exception in node v0.10.29, linux x64:

abnormal phantomjs exit code: 1
AssertionError: abnormal phantomjs exit code: 1
      at Console.assert (console.js:102:23)
      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/hebus/Documents/git/system/nodejs/searchEs/node_modules/phantom/phantom.js:153:28)
      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:809:12)
Running 1 tests in 1 runtime ... 100% done
```

Comment: That seems to suggest that you don't have a server running on port 3000. Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html), [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors. The event registering is done differently for a bridge between PhantomJS and node. Please see how it is done for your bridge.

Comment: this is produce by use grunt and buster plugin.Code is executed with node test/teft-file.js

Comment: @ArtjomB. the server is ok. I can see the request on it